# sftp to change directory on login

Tags: linux, ftp, cd, chroot

I have setup SFTP and setup chroot

```
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

Match Group ftpusers
        ChrootDirectory /home/sftp_chroot/%u
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

But how can I achive to cd to ftp dir in the users home on login?

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 16.10 LTS with OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016:

ChrootDirectory inside sshd_conf must be parent or the same as user home directory.

The correct way to set initial directory after login is write -d parameter to internal-sftp in /etc/ssh/sshd_conf

```
ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /ftp
```

Comment: Note... this breaks regular ssh.

Answer (score 1):

OK setting the users home directory to /ftp solves my problem

As when the user logs in the chroot `/home/sftp/chroot/<user>` becomes the root `/`. Then the user is put into home dir `/ftp`, which in affect is `/home/sftp/chroot/<user>/ftp`

Answer (score 0):

This is bad practice, because "jailing" the user in `/home/sftp_chroot/<user>` fixes security issues. You can change the chroot directory variable to whatever you want where `%u` is the name of the user if you really want this.

Comment: by ftp folder I mean /home/sftp_chroot/<user>/ftp, to change the chroot to ftp the parent folder needs be owned by root

Comment: You mean you want the user's home folder to be the same as the SFTp home folder ?